# Java: String objects matrix

Tags: java, string, sorting, matrix

I have a matrix of objects named "Worker" and in every "Worker" there's a String type variable called "fullname" (The names are without spaces, such as: SarahSmith).
I need to order each column of the matrix by the names **descend alphabetically**.
Now I used this method to order each column **alphabetically**:

```
    public static void secondChange(Worker[][] mat) {
    for (int m = 0; m < mat[0].length; m++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mat[0].length; i++) {
            int minindex = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < mat[0].length; j++) {
                if (mat[j][m].getName().compareTo(mat[minindex][m].getName()) < 0)
                    minindex = j;   
            }
            Worker temp = mat[i][m];
            mat[i][m] = mat[minindex][m];
            mat[minindex][m] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

and then i used this method to order each column **descending**:

```
    public static void rightOrder(Worker[][] mat){
    for (int m=0 ; m<mat[0].length ; m++)
    for (int i=0, j=(mat[0].length-1) ; i<(mat[0].length/2) || j>(mat[0].length/2) ; i++,j--){
        Worker temp = mat[i][m];
        mat[i][m] = mat[j][m];
        mat[j][m] = temp;
    }
}
```

After the second method the matrix will be back in it's original form instead of working the way i intended (The first method works fine).
Can anyone help? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging for a while i got the answer...

On the second method i need to run on `mat.length -1` and not on `mat[0].length-1`  ~!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but here's how you can use Java's standard and more efficient sort with a matrix, by creating a `List` wrapper for each column:

```
public static void sortColumnsDescending(Worker[][] matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++) {
        final int column = i;
        new AbstractList<Worker>() {
            @Override
            public int size() {
                return matrix.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Worker get(int row) {
                return matrix[row][column];
            }

            @Override
            public Worker set(int row, Worker element) {
                Worker prev = matrix[row][column];
                matrix[row][column] = element;
                return prev;
            }
        }.sort(Comparator.comparing(Worker::getName).reversed());
    }
}
```

Comment: It's for class.. so i can't use stuff like "list wrapper", i need to use the basics of String class and Matrix.